# Jquery set icon class based on value in array

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a classname on a list item based on if the value is in an array. 
The problem I'm facing now is that my code returns just one classname instead of several. I'm a bit stuck now.

What I do is getting some data from JSON. That data is a string that needs to be seperated by a comma. Those seperate values are in an array called `usp`.

Next I want to test all those values if they contain some text. If that's the case then create a classname based on the value.

To clarify:

First I get some JSON data which returns a string:

```
'Type 1,1 fase,16 ampere,4 to 8 meter,next day delivery'
```

Next I split that data, like so:

```
var usp = productUsps.split(',');
// returns: [ "Type 1", "1 fase", "16 ampere", "4 to 8 meter", "next day delivery" ]
```

Now I want to test if all those values contain a piece of text and if they match then set a class name, like so:

```
   // create icon classes based on usp title
    var className = '',
    reLength = new RegExp('meter' , "i" ),
    reType = new RegExp('type' , "i" ),
    reFase = new RegExp('fase' , "i"),
    reShip = new RegExp('delivery' , "i" ),
    reAmpere = new RegExp('ampere' , "i" );

   usp.forEach(function(item) {
      if( $.inArray(reLength, usp) ){ 
        className = 'icon-length'; 
      } else if ( $.inArray(reType, usp)){
        className = 'icon-type';
      } etc....

      uspHtml.push('<li><i class="bullit '+className+'"></i>'+item+'</li>');
    });
```

Whatever I try my code only returns just one class name, for example `ìcon-length`.

I also tried to test like this:

```
if (reFase.test(usp) )
   className = 'icon-fase';
else if (reShip.test(usp))
   className = 'icon-ship';
// etc etc....
```

What I'm I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to accomplish this? Any help greatly appreciated!!

Complete code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){  
 if(data.data_02){
    var productUsps = data.data_02; 
    var usp = productUsps.split(',');

    // create icons classes based on usp title
    var className = '',
    reLength = new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('meter') , "i" ),
    reType = new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('type') , "i" ),
    reFase = new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('fase') , "i"),
    reShip = new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('delivery') , "i" ),
    reAmpere = new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('ampere') , "i" );

   usp.forEach(function(item) {
      if( $.inArray(reLength, usp) ){ 
        className = 'icon-length'; 
      } else if ( $.inArray(reType, usp)){
        className = 'icon-type';
      } .... etc ....
      uspHtml.push('<li><i class="bullit '+className+'"></i>'+item+'</li>');
    });  
    uspHtml = uspHtml.join('');
 } else {
   return;
 }
}).done(function(){
  $this.find('.product-usps ul').html(uspHtml);
  setTimeout(function(){  $('.product-usps .loader').hide() }, 500);
});
```

Comment: if(jQuery.inArray(reLength, usp) !== -1) try this way and so on , based on your condition you have to replace your variable with reLength to reType and any other in your else if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
$.inArray(reLength, usp)
```

This will always be true as you're checking in the whole array.

Try this instead:

```
usp.forEach(function(item) {
  if (reLength.test(item)){ 
    className = 'icon-length'; 
  } else if (reType.test(item)){
    className = 'icon-type';
  } etc....
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work! It still returns a single classname.

Comment: I just tested it, it works for me. Can you please try without "getAjaxTranslation", i.e: `reLength = new RegExp( "meter" , "i" )` , also make sure you pass `item` in the regex test instead of whole array `usp`

Comment: I've managed to get it working. Your answer is not for 100% the answer I was looking for but you directed me in the correct way. So i'll accept your answer. Thx man!!